# Alias doesn't work, but the command it references does?

Tags: git, config, alias

Why does the alias does not have the same effect as typing the command which the alias "is equal to"? Sorry for such a short question, but it's really all right there in the picture.

[image]

Edit: Just in case this helps, here's all my aliases.

[image]

Comment: aliases are by default git-only, so piping probably doesnt work; try using a shell-alias (either in bash directly or using the "!" notation in git aliases, see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config at `alias.*`) to escape to the bash environment first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes don't work in aliases since the aliases are executed by `git`, not the shell.

You can do it using `!` to escape to the shell and execute git recursively though;

```
$ git config alias.test '!git ls-files -v | grep ^h'

$ git test
h test.c
h test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, git doesn't run `git ls-files -v | grep ^h`, but just search for the command ls-files

Try with: `!git ls-files -v | grep ^h`